# Rust Shared Memory Performance: Quickly Increment Indexes

Tags: rust

In Rust, what are the fastest constructs for working with shared memory?

As an example of shared memory, suppose there is a Vec of length `N`, and you have a stream of incoming slices on the vec `(start, end): (usize, usize)`. Within each slice, you want to increment every index in the slice.

Comment: What is your definition of *'shared memory'*? Inter-process shared? Do multiple threads get those streams? What in your question is regarding to 'shared'? A `Vec` is not shared, it's owned by something. What type of data is contained in the `Vec`? A slice is either `&[T]` or `&mut [T]`. If it is `&`, you cannot modify anything (unless interior mutability, hence the question for what data it contains), and if it is `&mut`, then it isn't shared by definition, so simply iterate over it and increase every element.

Comment: Atomics is the fastest you can get.

Comment: @Finomnis I don't really care what the Vec is, as long as you can access an index and get the count. For example Chayim Friedman is suggesting an Atomic. How is he suggesting? A vec of atomics?

Comment: @mkrieger1 good point, I meant idioms which let you write code that runs fast.

Comment: So what do you mean with *'shared'*? That the vector gets passed around to many places via shared reference? Be aware that a `Vec` is quite pointless if shared, as all of the functionality that make it more powerful than a simple array require `&mut`. So if you **just** want a sharable minimum-overhead concurrent piece of memory, you can use `&[AtomicU8]`. If you want reference counting instead of lifetimes, use `Rc<[AtomicU8]>`. If you need it across thread boundaries, use `Arc<[AtomicU8]>`. If you want to improve throughput, use data in your native size, like `Arc<[AtomicU64]>` on 64bit.

Comment: If its size is always identical, consider using `&[AtomicU8; SIZE]`. `Rc<[AtomicU8; SIZE]>` or `Arc<[AtomicU8; SIZE]>` instead, then all the range checks can be done at compile time.

Comment: You see now why I ask about your usecase? :) There are many options, each of which are better or worse depending on the usecase.

Comment: @Finomnis I don't care whether the Vec is shared or not, I just want its indexes to be able to be incremented by separate threads. This can be a Vec of shared constructs, or not. The use case seems pretty clear: you're getting a stream of data, and you want to keep track of a transformation of it, so that later you can access properties of it.

Comment: @Test If you want it on separate threads, then you do care that it's shared. This is the first time you mention multiple threads, and I think it's quite essential to the question. I only guessed **because** you wrote "shared". Please take a little more time in future questions to describe your problem in more detail. And if I ask you for important details, "i don't care" is not a helpful answer to either of us. If you read my very first question, multi-threading is exactly what I asked, and it took you three comments to acknowledge that.

Comment: *"The use case seems pretty clear"* - I have no idea how I should have inferred *"you're getting a stream of data, and you want to keep track of a transformation of it, so that later you can access properties of it"* from the very brief description in your question. Remember we are answering your question in our free time, to help you. It is in your best interest to answer our questions as best as you can. I'm not asking because I am trying to be mean, I'm asking because I don't really have an answer without more information.

Comment: I am just stating in general terms what the question stated specifically. "you have a stream of incoming slices" => "you're getting a stream of data". "Within each slice, you want to increment..." => "want to keep track of a transformation of it". "later you can access properties of it" is assumed because there is no purpose to keep track of data but to reference it later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we assume the following:

- our data should be `u8`
- multiple threads need highly concurrent access to the data
- they don't need to atomic access to multiple elements at once

Then I personally would go with `&[AtomicU8]`, or `Arc<[AtomicU8]>`. I would prefer `&[AtomicU8]` in all cases possible; `Arc` is only required if your memory is short lived.

```rust
use std::sync::atomic::{AtomicU8, Ordering};

fn thread_func(data: &[AtomicU8], mutations: impl IntoIterator<Item = (usize, usize)>) {
    for (start, end) in mutations.into_iter() {
        for value in &data[start..=end] {
            value.fetch_add(1, Ordering::Relaxed);
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let data: [AtomicU8; 10] = Default::default();

    println!("data: {:?}", data);

    std::thread::scope(|s| {
        s.spawn(|| thread_func(&data, [(0, 5), (2, 6), (0, 9)]));
        s.spawn(|| thread_func(&data, [(1, 4), (3, 5), (7, 8)]));
    });

    println!("data: {:?}", data);
}
```

```
data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
data: [2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 4, 2, 2, 2, 1]
```

---

Be aware that if you really want *"the fastest constructs"*, then don't simply take my word. Try out multiple things and benchmark.

For example, if your slices are large and the thread collisions are very small, it might be faster to use `Mutex<[u8]>` instead. This means thread collosions get a lot slower, but the actual iteration of each slice is quite a bit faster. Atomics don't have much overhead, but it's also not zero.

Comment: That's great. What kind of performance does AtomicU8 increments have?

Comment: Funny enough, a question about that very topic just popped up :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77747022/machine-level-atomic-instructions

Comment: The problem is that every atomic read/modify/write for a `u8` or any other integer needs to lock the memory. This prevents L1 cache optimization.

For really large scale high performance you could also think about partial locking like you have a `[Mutex<[u8]>]`, an array of lockable arrays. Of course the chunk size would need to be benchmarked, but depending on your problem, this might be faster. But we are now in high-performance optimization usecase. Don't do any of this if it's not necessary, avoid premature optimization and benchmark enough. And stop at 'good enough' where appropriate.

Comment: Ok, that makes perfect sense. Why does granular locking prevent cache optimization?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but from what I understand, it needs to signal to the shared L2 cache that the data cannot be modified for this cycle or something like this. But I'm not entirely sure, and it might be architecture dependent. Take my words with a grain of salt, though, I'm not deep into this topic.